# datetime has changed format mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

In a `Edit` action I retrieve a model from database and send it to the view. in the view have created a hidden tag for `createdDate` property of the model. When I click on `submitt` button to post back the model `modelstate.isvalid` is `false` and it generates this error.The value `20.10.2012 22:29:39` is not valid for `DateCreate`. when I right click and choose view source the hidden tag contains `20.10.2012 22:29:39` instead of `2012-10-22 22:29:39`. I don't know why the format of the date is changed. I have tried to solve problem and I think I am been convinced that it is best to don't use `DateTime` as a property of a model. It is best to have a string instead.

Comment: How did you create this hidden tag? Could you show the relevant portion of your view? Also are you using client side validation?

Comment: I use unobtrusive validation and I created the hidden like this @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedDate). Client side validation is true.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, it occurs because of globalization on the server vs the client. You can either setup the globalization in the web.config or convert date on the client side before it is sent to the server.

Comment: I solved it by reformating the date and add input type=hidden instead on HiddenFor extension method.